# Symfony2 order related entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a very simple OneToMany relationship, in this case a Series entity with many Episodes belonging to it.

I want to show, for each Series, its chapters, but when I retrieve the entity in the Controller like this:

```
$entity = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Series')->find($id);
```

Then in the template the chapters are retrieved in the order in which they were added, that is, by ID, and I want to show them ordered by number (which is one of its properties). How can I do that?

Comment: You can change the default ordering for the association. See http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/ordered-associations.html